# Where can I get wikipedia XML corpus

Tags: xml, search-engine, information-retrieval

I don't know if this can be asked here, but I have looked so hard for this and have reached deadend time and again. I'm working on a project for Information Retrieval Research. I've coded up my search engine but cannot test it because I need this xml corpus of Wikipedia. This I found http://www-connex.lip6.fr/~denoyer/wikipediaXML/ but it turns out useless. Please let me know if someone knows a way of getting me this corpus

Comment: Since http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download is not what you're looking for, maybe you should clarify what is it that you need, and why the link you gave in the description is useless.

Comment: Try to register on that link..you'll understand...the link mentioned here gives plain text and I need xml structured corpus....

Comment: If you don't make it easy for those that are trying to help you, then they're not going to help you. (a) The site says "This corpus is composed of more than 600,000 XML documents in english" so where's the plain text? (b) why is the wikipedia link not useful? Your post title says Wikipedia XML corpus.

Comment: Lucas when I try to register on that link, the site crashes with the message cannot connect to database. For the wikipedia links, I'm giving it second look, will let you know. Don't get offended, I was really frustrated with something. My apology if I came across as wrong.

Comment: I just tried to 'browse' the catalogs, and also got 'cannont connect to database'. How long have you been trying to get this access, hours or days? If more than 1 day, then maybe an email to one of the owners. Good luck. Please post back what you find.

Answer (score 3):

The page you provided looks like to be presenting the Wikipedia XML corpus used in the 2007 INEX workshop. I've found [this site](http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/departments/d5/software/inex/) which holds the wikipedia dataset used in 2009-2010 ad hoc (I think clustering too) track in INEX. I think you can use it as well.

Just in case you can use the official wikimedia XML dump: [English Wikipedia Dumps](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/).
More information and other languages: [Wikipedia Database Download](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aDatabase_download)